# Notify new Lead owner (through email)

Tags: leads, notification

Is it possible to simply customize notification email that notifies user (new Lead owner) when I assign Lead to a new owner?
I know it's possible to automatically send **default notification email**, but I need custom mails for almost 20 people.
If I use Assignment rules it's so comprehensive (too many assignment rules).

Is there any other solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: and why doesn't workflow or process builder work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing Trigger on Lead Update which will send mail to those 20 people.

See this post which might help you in writing that code -

http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/03/01/sending-emails-using-apex/

Comment: That's an option, but it's not recommended. I thought that there are some other solution. But when I search the web, there's nothing than Assignment rules and Queues.